# Generic covariance compile time safety checks

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

The reason why `List<T>` isn't covariant on `T`, while `IEnumerable<T>` *is* covariant on `T` is often illustrated by an example like this.

Given the following classes:

```
public class Fruit
{
}

public class Apple : Fruit
{
}

public class Banana : Fruit
{
}
```

The following is permitted:

```
public void Permitted()
{
    IEnumerable<Fruit> bananas = new List<Banana>
    {
        new Banana(),
        new Banana(),
        new Banana(),
    };

    foreach (Fruit banana in bananas)
    {
        // This is all good, because a banana "is a" fruit and
        // we can treat it as such.
    }
}
```

The following is disallowed:

```
public void Disallowed()
{
    // Compiler rejects this!
    List<Fruit> bananas = new List<Banana>
    {
        new Banana(),
        new Banana(),
        new Banana(),
    };

    // ...Otherwise we can add an apple to a list containing bananas
    bananas.Add(new Apple());
}
```

However, we can still achieve this by doing the following:

```
public void Loophole()
{
    // Compiler is happy again
    IEnumerable<Fruit> bananas = new List<Banana>
    {
        new Banana(),
        new Banana(),
        new Banana(),
    };

    // ...And now we can add an apple to a list of bananas
    bananas.ToList().Add(new Apple());
}
```

And of course we can just do this:

```
public void AlsoAllowed()
{
    var fruit = new List<Fruit>();
    fruit.Add(new Apple());
    fruit.Add(new Banana());
}
```

The common argument for `List<T>` not being covariant (as per my understanding) is that doing so would allow us to add any arbitrary base object to a collection which contains derived objects.  Maybe this is an oversimplification, but isn't that what the above examples are doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `bananas.ToList().Add(new Apple())`, `bananas.ToList()` creates a `List<Fruit>`. This is a list type which is able to contain any type of fruit. The fact that `new Apple()` can be added to that list makes sense.

`bananas` has type `List<Banana>`, which is a list type which is only able to contain bananas. There is no way to add `new Apple()` to this list, and your examples *don't* add `new Apple()` to this list. Your examples create a more tolerant list, and add to that, but leave the original list unmodified.

Comment: Just to add to this, in the second example, there is absolutely nothing wrong with adding `Apple`s and `Banana`s to `fruit` which is not only typed as but instantiated as a `List<Fruit>`.